# Why the file type is not supported after download using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
let beliver = () => {

 let data = "songs/beliver-imagine_dragons.mp3";

        const ToBLOB = new Blob([data], { type: 'audio/mpeg' });
        const sFileName = "beliver-imagine_dragons.mp3";

        let newLink = document.createElement("a");
        newLink.download = sFileName;

        newLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(ToBLOB);

        newLink.click();
}
```

```css
.downlogo {
 height: 60px;
 width: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<img src="images/downloadicon.png" onclick="beliver()" class="downlogo">

</body>
</html>
```

This is a simple code. There is an download icon named downicon.png and there is a onclick function associated with the icon that calls the function believer(). This function downloads the file beliver-imagine_dragons.mp3 . I am able to successfully download the mp3 file but when I open the file, there's an error : 'The file is either corrupted or the file format isn't supported' . I have tried changing the "type", but wasn't able to get the desired result.

Comment: `data` is a file path, not that file's contents.

Comment: `newLink.href = data`   blob construction would only be necessary if you are populating from an ArrayBuffer

Answer (score 0):

The Blob construction from data would only be necessary (and valid) if you are populating from data as an ArrayBuffer of the file contents.

You already have a URL to the file.  Just set the href to the URL.

```js
let beliver = () => {
  let data = "songs/beliver-imagine_dragons.mp3";

  //const ToBLOB = new Blob([data], { type: 'audio/mpeg' });
  const sFileName = "beliver-imagine_dragons.mp3";

  let newLink = document.createElement("a");

  newLink.href = data
  newLink.download = sFileName
  newLink.target = '_blank'

  newLink.click();
}
```

```css
.downlogo {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <img src="images/downloadicon.png" onclick="beliver()" class="downlogo">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I want the beliver() to download the beliver-imagine_dragons.mp3 file when I click the image(downloadicon.png). The changes that you made to the code will only play the song by displaying the default small audio player.

Comment: Now it is opening the audio link into another tab. But its still not downloading the file.

Comment: is it on the same origin/domain?